# How to narrow down Microsoft Teams bot to only upload files into one Sharepoint Site

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api

I am trying to figure out the correct permission and process to grant my Teams bot with permission to read/write files to *one* Microsoft SharePoint Site.

In the azure portal when configuring the permissions for the bot, I am giving it the following permissions:

[image]

This seems to be the only way I can successfully write to the Sharepoint Site. However, if I remove `Files.ReadWrite.All`, then I don't have permissions anymore and receive the following error when trying to do so:

> Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.

From what I've researched, I could give it `Sites.Selected` permissions within SharePoint, but this doesn't seem to change anything. I still have the ability to read/write to any sites I want, rather than just one specific one.

As a Teams bot, it seems to be an all or nothing type of permission. How can I give a bot permission to just one sharepoint site?

It seems like it would be possible [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get-permission?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), but this first requires *another* application with full control, which I don't have. Is there not a way as a user (who has full access to a site) to provide write access to a site for a bot or a way I can instruct IT to do this from the UI?

Answer (score 0):

**To restrict the Microsoft Bot Application to access only one SharePoint site**, check the below:

Grant Admin Consent to **`Sites.Selected`** Application API permission:

[image]

Use the below **PowerShell script** to grant access to only one SharePoint site:

```
$siteUrl = “https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testruk”
$clientId = “ClientID” 
$certThumbprint = “Thumbprint” 
$tenant = “xxx.onmicrosoft.com”

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive
$writeperm = Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Permissions “Write” -Site $siteUrl -AppId $clientId -DisplayName “PowerShell-SharepointOnline”
$PermissionId = Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppIdentity $clientId
Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Site $siteurl -PermissionId $(($PermissionId).Id) -Permissions “FullControl”
```

[image]

I connected to the SharePoint site using application and I am able to access the site:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant
```

[image]

Now, I connected the application to another SharePoint site and got **403 forbidden** error when trying to access the site:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant
```

[image]

> **Note** that: This will restrict access to specific site collections but not specific folders/files.

- Applications that use Microsoft Graph with their own identities have their application permissions exposed.
- Application permissions are full level access permissions granted to the Azure AD App.
- If the application has the **`Files.ReadWrite.All`** application permission granted, then application can access files from any OneDrive in the organization and **it cannot be restricted.**

**References:**

[Graph API - Restrict OneDrive/Sharepoint Access when using "Files.ReadWrite.All" and "Sites.ReadWrite.all" Permissions - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1139865/graph-api-restrict-onedrive-sharepoint-access-when) by CarlZhao-MSFT

[How to allow my app without user to access ONLY specific drive or folder - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/673127/how-to-allow-my-app-without-user-to-access-only-sp) by Vasil Michev

Comment: Thanks. I believe one important step that I noticed which appeared to be missing is that, in order to grant an application permission to a site, you must use another application that has full control over the site you're wanting to grant access to the other app to. I could be wrong, but this is what worked for me because without permissions to begin with, the app can't grant itself permission. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That also can be done. But I have not created another application with full control.

Comment: So with `Sites.Selected`, you used that same application to grant itself write permissions to a particular SharePoint site? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes I did the same and signed in as user

Comment: But you cannot narrow down the Files.ReadWrite.All application permission